# ASP.NET application Vs Page.Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Are the [ASP.NET application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplicationstate.aspx) and [Page.Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.application.aspx) the same?

Comment: Yes they are, Why are you asking?

Comment: `Page.Application` is a property which returns `HttpApplicationState` and the other link says what `HttpApplicationState` is. So what do you mean if they are the same?